# using Managed Media Aggregation

Tags: stream, media, rtsp, rtp

I have been trying to use the Managed Media Aggregation Open Source.

I have a server that is getting its source from another PC in my LAN.

**a few issues:**

1. I got my RtspClient to connect to my server,
   now I want to be able to work with the client (send play, pause, and actually see where the video plays) and haven't found any code examples for this.
2. I want to be able to stream a local video file in my computer through my server, is there a way to do it?
3. I tried to connect from VLC on my PC to the server (localhost) - did'nt work..

**Here is my code:**

```
public ServerExample()
    {
        //Create the server optionally specifying the port to listen on
        server = new RtspServer(554);


        source = new RtspSourceStream("RtspSourceTest",
                  "rtsp://192.168.30.11:5544/stream");

        // Add the stream to the server
        server.AddStream(source);

        // Start the server and underlying streams
        server.Start();

        //The server is now running,  you can access the stream  with VLC, QuickTime, etc
        AccessWithClient();
    }

    private void AccessWithClient()
    {
        RtspClient client = new RtspClient("rtsp://localhost:554/RtspSourceTest", RtspClient.ClientProtocolType.Tcp);
        client.Connect();
    }
```

any thoughts?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of that library.

Your example looks correct, Stack Overflow is not a forum for my library.

Post questions https://net7mma.codeplex.com/discussions if you need to after reviewing the other discussions to ensure your question is not answered.

Comment: Dear Julius, you are the author of that library/https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp ? Is there still a place to download it? Also many thanks for creating it and read your sad dog story from many years ago.. all the best!

Comment: https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma_core/tree/master/Common/Classes